# iOS multi-target support for Ionic?

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, testflight, ionic5

I'm using Ionic 5 to create multiplatform applications and Testflight to distribute iOS app to testers.

I would prefer Testflight users to not directly testing on production server so I found this [article](https://blog.usejournal.com/effective-environment-switching-in-ios-6df0b08e9556) which suggests submitting a different iOS target for Testflight.

Is there any way to make ionic works with multi target iOS apps?

Ideally it should be like:

- `ionic cap copy ios --prod` to copy to the "App (Production)" target
- `ionic cap copy ios` to copy to the "App (Testflight)" target.

Thanks